# What's the standard way of live streaming in 2020?

Tags: browser, streaming, live-streaming

I'd like to either 1) Stream my camera+mic or 2) Stream my desktop+mic (or OBS) to many people (1 to many) watching from a web browser. Since I'd like to communicate with people in real time low latency is highly preferred (1 second or less would be great).

What's the standard way of doing this today? I have no idea what twitch uses but from playing with rtmp (using the nginx rtmp module) there seems to be a 4+second delay (or maybe I configured it poorly) and doesn't seem to have native browser support. People watching will use their desktop computers but some may be watching from their phones.

Am I to use webrtc somehow (does it support 1 to many? what software do I use)? Or HLS (which seems to want recordings, what config do I want for a live video)? What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely difficult question. If you only need a hand full of viewers (around 10 or less), WebRTC  the way to go. If there is a lot of viewers, and you can spend a lot of money, WebRTC is still a good choice, but the bandwidth cost can add up. If you don’t have a lot of money, but need a lot of viewers, you need cheeper bandwidth, this means using an HTTP CDN, and HLS or DASH which adds latency, but is cheeper to operate. If you have 100+ million dollars, you can build your own WebRTC cdn and have the best of both.

So to answer your question, there is no standard way. It depends on your circumstance, use cases and budget.

Comment: So what would I need? A STUN server and a static html page? I followed a few directions to install STUN on debian but none of the tutorials seem to work. From memory either the package was obsolete, had some kind of conflict or the configuration didn't seem to work with the demo

Comment: Please do not ask new questions in comments. New questions should be their own posts.

Comment: TBH that was part of the original question but I got my answer from a new more specific question about WebRTC.